# For XML Path - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have data in SQL Server table as shown below.

```
**Name      Date        AA   BB  CC**
Customer1   3-Mar-15    234  56  4567
Customer2   4-Mar-15    55   66   77
```

Now I want this data to be formatted as below in XML.

```
<ReturnsList>
    <Return Label='AA' Days = 1 value = '234'></Return>
    <Return Label='BB' Days = 2 value = '56'></Return>
    <Return Label='CC' Days = 3 value = '4567'></Return>
</ReturnsList>
<ReturnsList>
    <Return Label='AA' Days = 1 value = '55'></Return>
    <Return Label='BB' Days = 2 value = '66'></Return>
    <Return Label='CC' Days = 3 value = '77'></Return>
</ReturnsList>
```

I have tried different ways like :

```
SELECT 

 (Select AA  AS "AA", 

   BB AS "BB",

   CC AS "CC"

from table
for xml path('Return') ,type
)
FOR XML PATH ('ReturnsList');
```

I am not getting xml format as expected.

Can anyone please help ?

Thank you,
Mittal.

Comment: I have updated above example, as it should work for all the rows. How can I achieve this with below CTE query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR XML PATH` operates on rowsets. Hence, you have to transpose a single row of your data into a set of rows. You can use `UNPIVOT` for this:

```
SELECT Name, Labels, LabelValue, 
       CASE 
          WHEN Labels = 'AA' THEN 1
          WHEN Labels = 'BB' THEN 2
          WHEN Labels = 'CC' THEN 3
       END AS [Days]
FROM 
   (SELECT Name, AA, BB, CC
    FROM #mytable) p
UNPIVOT (
   LabelValue FOR Labels IN ([AA], [BB], [CC])
)AS unpvt
```

**Output:**

```
    Name        Labels  LabelValue  Days
   --------------------------------------
    Customer1   AA      234         1
    Customer1   BB      56          2
    Customer1   CC      4567        3
```

You can now wrap the above query in a `CTE` and apply `FOR XML PATH` to get the desired result:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    ... above query here ...
)
SELECT Labels AS "@Label", [Days] AS "@Days", LabelValue AS "@value" 
FROM CTE
FOR XML PATH('Return'), root('ReturnsList')
```

For more than one dates, customers you can adjust the above query with an appropriate use of `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Can I use this CTE query with select statement? As I want to insert this xml output to another table with other columns from #mytable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 'AA' as [Return/@Label],
       1    as [Return/@Days] ,
       T.AA as [Return/@Value],
       null,
       'BB' as [Return/@Label],
       2    as [Return/@Days] ,
       T.BB as [Return/@Value],
       null,
       'CC' as [Return/@Label],
       3    as [Return/@Days] ,
       T.CC as [Return/@Value],
       null
from table as T
for xml path('ReturnList');
```

Result:

```xml
<ReturnList>
  <Return Label="AA" Days="1" Value="234" />
  <Return Label="BB" Days="2" Value="56" />
  <Return Label="CC" Days="3" Value="4567" />
</ReturnList>
<ReturnList>
  <Return Label="AA" Days="1" Value="55" />
  <Return Label="BB" Days="2" Value="66" />
  <Return Label="CC" Days="3" Value="77" />
</ReturnList>
```